# Facebook Graph API - Get JSON friend list

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I need to generate a json array from the graph api that is formatted like this ->

```
[
   {"id": "12345678", "name": "Person 1"}, 
   {"id": "12345678", "name": "Person 2"}, 
   {"id": "12345678", "name": "Person 3"}
]
```

I can generate a list like this with php, but it is very slow. 
Is there a quicker way to do this using the js sdk?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query the graph you can specify which fields you want to be returned using a GET parameter, like this (obviously add a valid access token):

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name

which returns

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "010101010101",
         "name": "Person"
      },
      {
         "id": "01010101010101",
         "name": "Another Person"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can use that query however you like, in JS you would use `FB.api()`.

You can play around with adding various filters to the test URLs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/